# Not able to Check installed Java version in Win-10 through NSIS installer for JAVA -8 , 64-bit and above

Tags: java, windows, registry, installation, nsis

The installer works fine for Win-7, Win-8,but works weird for Win-10. 
My Java Version Check Function is -

```
Function checkJavaVersion
${If} ${RunningX64}
    ${registry::Read} "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environmen" "JAVA_HOME" $0 $1
    MessageBox MB_OK "64 bit JAVA Home - $0"
    MessageBox MB_OK "64 bit JAVA Home - $1"

    ${registry::Read} "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" "CurrentVersion" $0 $1
    MessageBox MB_OK "64 bit JRE - $0"
    MessageBox MB_OK "64 bit JRE - $1"
    ${If} $0 == "" 
        ${registry::Read} "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit" "CurrentVersion" $0 $1
        MessageBox MB_OK "64 bit JDK - $0"
        MessageBox MB_OK "64 bit JDK - $1"
    ${EndIf}

    ${registry::Read} "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" "CurrentVersion" $0 $1
    MessageBox MB_OK "32 bit JRE - $0"
    MessageBox MB_OK "32 bit JRE - $1"
    ${If} $0 == "" 
        ${registry::Read} "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit" "CurrentVersion" $0 $1
        MessageBox MB_OK "32 bit JDK - $0"
        MessageBox MB_OK "32 bit JDK - $1"
    ${EndIf}

${Else}
    ${registry::Read} "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" "CurrentVersion" $0 $1
    MessageBox MB_OK "32 bit JRE - $0"
    MessageBox MB_OK "32 bit JRE - $1"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

after running this sample installer in different systems I have found out that for Win-10(64-bit system) with Java 8 (64- bit) installed it is not able to recognize the JAVA version, not even in elevated mode.

Also for Win-10(64- bit system) with JAVA 8(32-bit) installed `HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` this path redirecting the registry search to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`  so in both cases (32 bit & 64 bit Java Version check) Java version is found                                                                        even in Elevated mode this behaves the same,

Please find the attached result for more detailed result. 
[image: Java Version Check behavior, in different machines]

This open issue [NSIS installer issue](https://github.com/daisy/pipeline-assembly/issues/108) can be referred for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 64-bit detection code does not make sense, NSIS defaults to the 32-bit registry view in 32-bit installers. `WOW6432Node` is a [reserved name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view) and you should not really use it if possible. Elevating a installer does not change how registry redirection works.

It should probably look something like this:

```
${If} ${RunningX64}
  SetRegView 64
  ${registry::Read} ... $0 $1
  ...
${EndIf}
SetRegView 32
${If} $0 == "" 
  ${registry::Read} ... $0 $1
  ...
${EndIf}
```

According to the page you linked to, Java v9 changed the registry path and names so you need to update your code to handle those as well.

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked. But I still I want to know why  ${registry::Read} "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environmen" "JAVA_HOME" $0 $1 , this registry search is not working even with your said fix.

Comment: "Environment" not "Environmen"

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using:

```
SetRegView 64
```

So function which is use for checking is looking like this:

```
Function LocateJVM
;Check for Java version and location
Push $0
Push $1

ReadRegStr $JAVA_VER HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" CurrentVersion
StrCmp "" "$JAVA_VER" Check64Bit CheckJavaVer

Check64Bit:
    SetRegView 64
    ReadRegStr $JAVA_VER HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" CurrentVersion
    StrCmp "" "$JAVA_VER" JavaNotPresent CheckJavaVer

JavaNotPresent:
    StrCpy $JAVA_INSTALLATION_MSG "Java Runtime Environment nije instalirana na Vašem računaru. Da bi ste pokrenuli ovaj program potrebno je da instalirate Java 1.7 ili noviju."
    Pop $1
    Pop $0
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "Molim instalirajte Javu 1.7 ili noviju."

CheckJavaVer:
    ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\$JAVA_VER" JavaHome
    GetFullPathName /SHORT $JAVA_HOME "$0"
    StrCpy $0 $JAVA_VER 1 0
    StrCpy $1 $JAVA_VER 1 2
    StrCpy $JAVA_VER "$0$1"
    IntCmp 17 $JAVA_VER FoundCorrectJavaVer FoundCorrectJavaVer JavaVerNotCorrect

FoundCorrectJavaVer:
    IfFileExists "$JAVA_HOME\bin\javaw.exe" 0 JavaNotPresent
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "Found Java: $JAVA_VER at $JAVA_HOME"
    Goto Done

JavaVerNotCorrect:
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "Molim instalirajte Javu 1.7 ili noviju."
    StrCpy $JAVA_INSTALLATION_MSG "Verzija Java Runtime Environment instalirana na Vašem računaru je $JAVA_VER. Da bi ste pokrenuli ovaj program potrebno je da instalirate Java 1.7 ili noviju."

Done:
    Pop $1
    Pop $0

FunctionEnd
```